# How to create a bash/zsh status bar on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, zsh

I would like to have all the information about working environment: git branch, name of virtualenv, current folder on the first line of the terminal window, always. In my idea it should look something like this:

```
[git branch](virtualenv)user@host:<pwd> # this part shouldn't move
...
here is standard terminal output
$ # last line for writing commands
```

Is it possible? If so, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Should this be only shown when the shell is waiting for input or all of the time, so even during output of an program or when an application like `vim` or `less` is open?

Comment: @Adaephon Only when shell is waiting for input. But, if it is easier to show it all the time - I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

For `zsh`, just add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
zmodload zsh/terminfo
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
statusbar () {
  echoti sc                   # Save cursor position.
  echoti home                 # Move cursor to top left of window.

  # -n: Don't append a newline.
  # -P: Expand prompt escape codes.
  print -nP -- "[$( git branch --show-current 2> /dev/null )]($VIRTUAL_ENV)%n@%M:%~"

  echoti el                   # Clear to end of line
  echoti rc                   # Restore cursor position.
}
add-zsh-hook precmd statusbar # Call before each new prompt.
```